# How to represent a many to many relationship with Crow Feet diagram

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database and I want to represent the relationship between users and groups:

A user can be on zero or more groups.
A group can have one or more users.

Using Microsoft Visio 2013 I've drawn this diagram:

[image]

Is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

Of course you no longer actually have a many-to-many relationship in your model.  You are no longer "representing" the relationship, as you say in your question.  You have, in fact, *resolved* the relationship into an association entity type with two one-to-many relationships.